# Locking a variable during instance reassignment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Let's say I have two threads: `Thread-A` and `Thread-B`

`Thread-A` is on a schedule to update a local variable within its class:

```java
public class SomeClass {

    private List<String> aSpecialList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Scheduled(....)
    public void updateASpecialList() {
        List<String> aBetterSpecialList = new ArrayList<>()

        // all these great things happen to aBetterSpecialList
        ...

        aSpecialList = aBetterSpecialList;
    }

    public List<String> getASpecialList() {
        return aSpecialList;
    }
}
```

Now, `Thread-B` attempts to access this list (`SomeClass::getASpecialList()`) when `Thread-A` is about to perform variable reassignment. Is there any possibility that this will cause any form of concurrency issues if I don't lock `aSpecialList`?

Comment: depends on the use you will do on `Thread-B` of the returned list

Comment: what kind of concurrency issues are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia No operations are performed on that list. But say if I did, it wouldn't matter? `Thread-A` makes no modifications to the list and `Thread-B` has already stored the location of that instance by invoking `getASpecialList()`, right?

Comment: Without synchronization your `Thread-B` may not receive fresh value of a list after `Thread-A` reassigned it and `Thread-B` calls `getASpecialList()`

Comment: @Ivan And that is okay. I don't mind if `Thread-B` has an older copy of the list.

Comment: concurrent problems occurs on modification of the same object, if you reassign, you are editing the pointer, not the value, therefore there should not be problem, if not the one already mentioned (so getting no the latest actual value)

Comment: An AtomicReference is sometimes useful here (where you want the new list to be visible in a timely manner after it is generated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `aSpecialList` is not volatile, then `aSpecialList = aBetterSpecialList` is [an unsafe publication](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication).
Because of that, we don't get so called `happen-before` relation (a term from the JMM) when `Thread-B` reads `aSpecialList`.
As a result we get the following concurrency problems (also called data races):

1. the read of `aSpecialList` by `Thread-B` is racy: every read independently might return any of the values ever written to the field by any other thread during the whole lifetime of the program
2. any read by `Thread-B` of any field inside the `ArrayList` stored in `aSpecialList` is also racy.
   For example, `Thread-B` can see inconsistent values for the [`size`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L143) of the `ArrayList` and its internal[`elementData`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L136) array.

One of the solutions is to make `aSpecialList` volatile, then:

- `Thread-B` is guaranteed to see writes to `aSpecialList` by `Thread-A`
- `Thread-B` is also guaranteed to see the internal state of `ArrayList` stored in `aSpecialList` as it was at the moment of publication

Additionally I would also make the list you write into `aSpecialList`  [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)).